# Read variable from AWK

Tags: linux, shell, variables, unix, awk

I'm trying to get memory info by this command:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
cat /proc/meminfo | grep "MemFree" | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $2 $4 }' | read numA numB
echo $numA
```

I'm getting this

```
+ awk '{ print $2 $4 }'
+ read numA numB
+ tail -n 1
+ grep MemFree
+ cat /proc/meminfo
+ echo
```

My attempts to read these data to variable were unsuccessful. My question is how I can read this to variables? I want to read how many memory is free like: 90841312 KB

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `BASH` you can reduce your complex commands to this:

```
read -r _ numA _ numB < <(grep MemFree /proc/meminfo | tail -n 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Assign the output directly to your variable:

```
var=$(cat /proc/meminfo | grep "MemFree" | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $2 $4 }')
echo $var
```

Comment: UUOC. That can be shortened to `var=$(awk '/^MemFree:/{print $2 $4}' /proc/meminfo)`.

Answer (score 0):

BTW: If you print multiple vales from awk, you need a separator:

```
$ echo "11 22" | awk '{print $1 }'
11
$ echo "11 22" | awk '{print $2}'
22
$ echo "11 22" | awk '{print $1 $2}'
1122
 ^ note no space there...
```

You either need a comma:

```
$ echo "11 22" | awk '{print $1,$2}'
11 22
```

Or physicality:

```
$ echo "11 22" | awk '{print $1"    "$2}'
11    22
```

Because without separation, the command substitution not read what you intend:

```
$ read -r f1 f2 <<< $(echo "11 22" | awk '{print $1 $2}')
$ echo $f1
1122
echo $f2

# f1 got two fields and nada for f2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr=( $(awk '/MemFree/{split($0,a)} END{print a[2], a[4]}' /proc/meminfo) )
echo "${arr[0]}"
echo "${arr[1]}"
```